# siunitx causes compilation errors after updating MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: siunitx

After updating my MiKTeX 2.9 today all my documents crash on compilation, if siunitx is loaded, with ERROR ! Undefined control sequence. ...

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 10 July 2018
% BRIEF DESCRIPTION:
%  After updating my MiKTeX 2.9 today all my documents crash, if siunitx is loaded, with 
%  ERROR ! Undefined control equence.<argument> 
%  \seq_const_from_clist:Nn\c__siunitx_old_options_seq {addsign,all... }
%=======================
%\usepackage{siunitx}
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
Hi there!
\end{document}
```

The log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6400 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.7.10)  11 JUL 2018 17:35
entering extended mode
**./MWE_Template.tex
(MWE_Template.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.14> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\siunitx\siuni
tx.sty" ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty"
Package: expl3 2017/09/18 L3 programming layer (loader) 

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
Package: expl3 2017/09/18 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count87
\l_tmpa_int=\count88
\l_tmpb_int=\count89
\g_tmpa_int=\count90
\g_tmpb_int=\count91
\g__intarray_font_int=\count92
\g__prg_map_int=\count93
\c_log_iow=\count94
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count95
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count96
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count97
\l__iow_indent_int=\count98
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count99
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count100
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count101
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_rand_size_int=\count109
\c__fp_rand_four_int=\count110
\c__fp_rand_eight_int=\count111
\l__sort_length_int=\count112
\l__sort_min_int=\count113
\l__sort_top_int=\count114
\l__sort_max_int=\count115
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count116
\l__sort_block_int=\count117
\l__sort_begin_int=\count118
\l__sort_end_int=\count119
\l__sort_A_int=\count120
\l__sort_B_int=\count121
\l__sort_C_int=\count122
\l__tl_build_start_index_int=\count123
\l__tl_build_index_int=\count124
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count125
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count126
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count127
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count128
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count129
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count130
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count131
\l__regex_balance_int=\count132
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count133
\l__regex_mode_int=\count134
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count135
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count136
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count137
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count138
\c__regex_catcode_D_int=\count139
\c__regex_catcode_S_int=\count140
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count141
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count142
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count143
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count144
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count145
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count146
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count147
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count148
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count149
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count150
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count151
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count152
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count153
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count154
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count155
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count156
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count157
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count158
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count159
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count160
\l__regex_step_int=\count161
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count162
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count163
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count164
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count165
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count166
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count167
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count168
\g__debug_trace_regex_int=\count169
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen109
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen110
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen111
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen112
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen113
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen114
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen115
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen116
\l__box_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box32
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen118
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen119
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen120
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen121
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen122
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen123
\c_empty_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen124
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3pdfmode.def"
File: l3pdfmode.def 2017/03/18 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
\l__driver_color_stack_int=\count170
\l__driver_tmp_box=\box41
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\xparse\xparse.sty"
Package: xparse 2017/09/18 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count171
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count172
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count173
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count174
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count175
)
Package: siunitx 2018/05/17 v2.7s A comprehensive (SI) units package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\ex@=\dimen134
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\array.sty"
Package: array 2016/10/06 v2.4d Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen135
\extrarowheight=\dimen136
\NC@list=\toks15
\extratabsurround=\skip49
\backup@length=\skip50
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\l3keys2e\l3keys2e.sty"
Package: l3keys2e 2017/09/18 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
\l__siunitx_tmp_box=\box42
\l__siunitx_tmp_dim=\dimen137
\l__siunitx_tmp_int=\count176

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \seq_const_from_clist:Nn 
                                    \c__siunitx_old_options_seq {addsign,all...
l.258   }

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...list:Nn \c__siunitx_old_options_seq 
                                                  {addsign,allowlitunits,all...
l.258   }

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.258   }

You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

\l__siunitx_number_mantissa_length_int=\count177
\l__siunitx_number_uncert_length_int=\count178
\l__siunitx_round_int=\count179
\l__siunitx_process_decimal_int=\count180
\l__siunitx_process_uncertainty_int=\count181
\l__siunitx_process_fixed_int=\count182
\l__siunitx_process_integer_min_int=\count183
\l__siunitx_process_precision_int=\count184
\l__siunitx_group_min_int=\count185
\l__siunitx_angle_marker_box=\box43
\l__siunitx_angle_unit_box=\box44
\l__siunitx_angle_marker_dim=\dimen138
\l__siunitx_angle_unit_dim=\dimen139
\l__siunitx_unit_int=\count186
\l__siunitx_unit_denominator_int=\count187
\l__siunitx_unit_numerator_int=\count188
\l__siunitx_unit_prefix_int=\count189
\l__siunitx_unit_prefix_base_int=\count190
\l__siunitx_unit_prefix_gram_int=\count191
\l__siunitx_number_product_int=\count192
\c__siunitx_one_fill_skip=\skip51
\l__siunitx_table_unit_align_skip=\skip52
\l__siunitx_table_exponent_dim=\dimen140
\l__siunitx_table_integer_dim=\dimen141
\l__siunitx_table_mantissa_dim=\dimen142
\l__siunitx_table_marker_dim=\dimen143
\l__siunitx_table_result_dim=\dimen144
\l__siunitx_table_uncert_dim=\dimen145
\l__siunitx_table_fill_pre_dim=\dimen146
\l__siunitx_table_fill_post_dim=\dimen147
\l__siunitx_table_fill_mid_dim=\dimen148
\l__siunitx_table_pre_box=\box45
\l__siunitx_table_post_box=\box46
\l__siunitx_table_mantissa_box=\box47
\l__siunitx_table_result_box=\box48
\l__siunitx_table_number_align_skip=\skip53
\l__siunitx_table_text_align_skip=\skip54
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareBinaryPrefix with sig. 'mmm' on line 7237.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareSIPostPower with sig. 'mm' on line 7240.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareSIPrefix with sig. 'mmm' on line 7243.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareSIPrePower with sig. 'mm' on line 7246.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareSIQualifier with sig. 'mm' on line 7249.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareSIUnit with sig. 'O{}mm' on line 7252.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareSIUnitWithOptions with sig. 'mmm' on line 7255.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \ang with sig. 'o>{\SplitArgument {2}{;}}m' on line 7270.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \num with sig. 'om' on line 7279.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \numlist with sig. 'o>{\SplitList {;}}m' on line 7288.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \numrange with sig. 'omm' on line 7297.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \SIlist with sig. 'o>{\SplitList {;}}mm' on line 7309.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \SIrange with sig. 'ommm' on line 7321.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \SI with sig. 'omom' on line 7333.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \sisetup with sig. 'm' on line 7336.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \tablenum with sig. 'om' on line 7351.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \si with sig. 'om' on line 7363.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \numInBookmark with sig. 'om' on line 7410.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \numrangeInBookmark with sig. 'omm' on line 7412.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \SIInBookmark with sig. 'omom' on line 7414.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \SIlistInBookmark with sig. 'omm' on line 7416.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \SIrangeInBookmark with sig. 'ommm' on line 7418.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \siInBookmark with sig. 'om' on line 7419.
.................................................
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1
)
Overfull \hbox (6018.29338pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 258--11
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 addsign,allowlitunits,allowoptarg,allowzeroexp,alsoload,angfo
rmat,anglesep,astroang,closeerr,closrfrac,closerange,colour,colorall,colourall,
colorneg,colourneg,colourunits,colourunits,colorvalues,colourvalues,decimalsymb
ol,debug,detectdisplay,digitsep,dp,emulate,errspace,eVcorra,eVcorrb,expbase,exp
product,fixdp,fixsf,fraction,inlinebold,loctolang,log,load,mathOmega,mathcelsiu
s,mathdegree,mathminute,mathmu,mathringA,mathrm,mathsOmega,mathscelsius,mathsde
gree,mathsecond,mathsf,mathsminute,mathsmu,mathsringA,mathsrm,mathssecond,maths
sf,mathstt,mathtt,negcolor,negcolour,noload,numaddn,numcloseerr,numdecimal,numd
igits,numdiv,numexp,numgobble,numopenerr,numprod,numsign,obeyall,obeybold,obeyf
amily,obeymode,obeyitalic,openerr,openfrac,openrange,padangle,padnumber,per,pre
fixbase,prefixproduct,prefixsymbolic,prespace,redefsymbols,repeatunits,retainpl
us,seperr,sepfour,sf,sign,slash,stickyper,strictarc,tabalign,tabalignexp,tabaut
ofit,tabexpalign,tabformat,tabnumalign,tabparseonly,tabtextalign,textOmega,text
celsius,textdegree,textminute,textmode,textmu,textringA,textrm,textsecond,texts
f,texttt,tightpm,tophrase,trapamigerr,trapambigfrac,trapambigrange,unitcolor,un
itcolour,unitmathrm,unitmathsf,unitmathsrm,unitmathssf,unitmathstt,unitmathtt,u
nitmode,unitsep,unitspace,valuecolor,valuecolour,valuemathrm,valuemathsf,valuem
athsrm,valuemathssf,valuemathstt,valuemathtt,valuemode,valuesep,xspace
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 258--11

 []

(MWE_Template.aux)
\openout1 = `MWE_Template.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.

("C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\siunitx\siuni
tx-abbreviations.cfg"
File: siunitx-abbreviations.cfg 2017/11/26 v2.7k siunitx: Abbreviated units
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 13.
 [1

{C:/Users/Reinhard Neuwirth/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
 (MWE_Template.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10425 strings out of 493318
 232869 string characters out of 3138960
 241354 words of memory out of 3000000
 14010 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 531681 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 32i,4n,33p,10365b,275s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on MWE_Template.pdf (1 page, 18428 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 10 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Please, add the *exact* error message like you find in the log file. The whole log file would be even better.

Comment: No problems here. Did run updates as user *and* as admin?

Comment: log file too long to be sent as comment. Wish I knew how to send the log as an attachment.

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...list:Nn \c__siunitx_old_options_seq 
                                                  {addsign,allowlitunits,all...
l.258   }
         
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Comment: @egreg Just sent the error message part of the log generated when compiling with siunitx.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth Please, add it to the question. Probably the whole log file will be better: in my experiment, the log file is 18K, so you can paste it here.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes I updated both

Comment: Your system is not up-to-date. Your expl3 is clearly older than on my system. You must update it in admin mode.

Comment: For more help on updates see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864. You probably only updated your system as User and not in Admin mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the part of the log file that reads

```
("C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\siunitx\siuni
tx.sty" ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty"
Package: expl3 2017/09/18 L3 programming layer (loader)
```

A bit further on you find

```
Package: siunitx 2018/05/17 v2.7s A comprehensive (SI) units package
```

and there's a mismatch of versions. The problem seems to be in the fact that you updated `siunitx` in “User” mode rather than “Admin” mode and indeed `siunitx` is loaded from a directory under your user path.

Always update in “Admin” mode and do *full* updates.

The problem is that `\seq_const_from_clist:Nn` has been introduced on 2017-11-28, but you're using a release of `expl3` earlier than that.

Comment: I now realize that my updates did not finish successfully and bombed out while updating "oberdiek". Removing oberdiek from the list and updating in both 'User' and 'Admin' mode fixed the 'siunitx' problem. Life was not meant to be perfect, I now find I can no longer invoke the MiKTeX Package Manager - responds by telling me it cannot find the mpm_mfc.exe and mpm_mfc_admin.exe files in 'User' and 'Admin' mode respectively. I suppose a re-install of MiKTeX will take care of that problem.

Comment: By the way, how did you manage to format the log file, which I supplied through an edit, correctly? I had given up trying and presented it like a dog's breakfast.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth Paste the code, select it and click on the `{}` icon.